# Signing and Deploying Windows app (appxbundle)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, signing

We have build an Windows native app (aapxbundle). We want to ship to a customer.

The certificates used in my company are owned by my company and customer has different set of certificates.

When we ship the appxbundle file it is already signed by our certificate. And hence customer is not able to install it because our certificate is not installed on their device.

What is recommended way to achieve such signing and deployment ?

Regards, Ashwani Kr Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can send your certificate to customer. The customer can add your certificate as trusted on computer/network/domain.
- You can buy certificate (Verisign, for example) and sign your program using it.